# Can I send a <shift> keypress to Windows from Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard

There is a function `'w32-toggle-lock-key` to, effectively, simulate a press of <kbd>capslock</kbd>, <kbd>numlock</kbd>, or <kbd>scroll-lock</kbd> key. Is there a similar function to simulate a <kbd>shift</kbd> key by itself (*not* <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>something else</kbd>)?

The reason I need this is because I have <kbd>shift</kbd> bound to switch languages in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is no.  For the same reasons discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840478/mapping-caps-lock-to-control-from-within-emacs-on-windows/840645#840645), namely that shift is a *modifier*, and Windows is swallowing the keypress.

The easiest way to see if Emacs responds to a key is to ask for help on a key

```
C-h k <press-key>
```

If Emacs tells you what is bound to that key, you're golden.  If Emacs seems to be waiting for more input (and after about 2 seconds shows you the key in the minibuffer), then you're still good - the key is just mapped to a prefix map (e.g. <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd>).  If Emacs does nothing and is still waiting for you to type something at the prompt

```
Describe key (or click or menu item):
```

then you know Emacs hasn't received an event.  This is what happens when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same apply to `<language-change>` (which Emacs treats like a key)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think emacs can do it - you are asking for something very particular... Since you are on Windows, one thing you can try is [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com), by writing a script with something like

```
Send {Shift}
```

And call the script from emacs. Warning: this is untested.

Comment: Yes, this _is_ a possibility.