# Emacs and toggle-input-method

Tags: emacs, xorg

Is there any chance to change in Emacs 23.1.1 a keybinding for `(toggle-input-method)` to `<Meta+Shift>` or `<Alt+Shift>` (because I use `<Alt>` as `<Meta>`)?

This, obviously, doesn't work:

```
(global-set-key [(meta shift)] 'toggle-input-method)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much a duplicate question... see [elisp how to check if shift key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477755/elisp-how-to-check-if-shift-key-is-pressed).  <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> are both key modifiers, and because of that you cannot bind any commands to them directly.