# Is there a way to map the tab key to meta in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, shortcut

I'm looking to rebind `Meta` to the tab key in my emacs environment. I've looked around but been unable to find anything other than binding it to `command` or `option`, which are slightly better but still not ideal.

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use the ESC key instead of the TAB key?

Comment: @Thomas, I was looking for a more natural hand position, escape is just as bad as alt for me. After getting this answer I settled on just using the `command` key (I'm on a mac).

Comment: The reason I asked was because TAB is often used for indentation in Emacs, and so it might not even be a good idea to rebind it, unless you're happy with using some other key for indentation instead.

Comment: I sure could use this one as well. I'm moving to emacs from vim. I use alt-tab for window switching so I want tab in my general environment. But I want tab to be my meta in emacs ... *sigh* one day we'll get it done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in Emacs alone, you need to modify the keymap in your window system (*nux, Mac, MS Windows).

See the similar questions for the reasoning: [Mapping Caps Lock to Control from within Emacs on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840478/mapping-caps-lock-to-control-from-within-emacs-on-windows), [elisp how to check if Shift key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477755/elisp-how-to-check-if-shift-key-is-pressed), and [Can I send a  keypress to Windows from Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043073/can-i-send-a-shift-keypress-to-windows-from-emacs).

You *can* make the change in your window system - but it'd be helpful to know what that is...

Comment: Trey, I was wondering if it might be possible to use Emacs' translation keymaps to hack around it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Thomas You could probably change `TAB` to be a prefix key and get close to what the asker is wanting - but you'd have to do a bunch of remapping in all the different modes...

Comment: sure but you could have a mode-hook that walks over the mode's keymap and remaps everything automatically.

Comment: @Thomas likely not a mode-hook (run once every time a mode is entered), but after each of the libraries is run (only run once per setting up the mode's keymap).  and you'd also need to find new bindings for the functionality not available from TAB, which might be tricky (e.g. yasnappet).  It could be done, but it would take a lot of effort - probably more than a SO answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use OS X, you can install KeyRemap4MacBook and use a [private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>EMACS</appname>
    <equal>org.gnu.Emacs</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>tabtometa</name>
    <identifier>tabtometa</identifier>
    <only>EMACS</only>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::TAB, KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::TAB</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

It changes tab to option when held but keeps it as tab when pressed.

If you want to use option to insert non-ASCII characters, change `OPTION_L` to `CONTROL_R` and use:

```
(setq ns-option-modifier 'nil)
(setq ns-right-control-modifier 'meta)
```